# Octobot Connection shutdown issue with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

We are using Octobot as a consumer for RabbitMQ. We frequently see connection shutdown issue, and get's following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.flush(SocketFrameHandler.java:142)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.flush(AMQConnection.java:481)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:125)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:316)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:292)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:285)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:376)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:516)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:533)
at com.urbanairship.octobot.RabbitMQ.getConnection(RabbitMQ.java:56)
at com.urbanairship.octobot.ChannelPool.initialize(ChannelPool.java:54)
at com.urbanairship.octobot.ChannelPool$ResetShutdownListener.shutdownCompleted(ChannelPool.java:41)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ShutdownNotifierComponent.notifyListeners(ShutdownNotifierComponent.java:75)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:548)
[AMQP Connection] ERROR ChannelPool  - Could not connect to RabbitMQ. Sleeping for 1 seconds.
com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:348)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:516)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:533)
at com.urbanairship.octobot.RabbitMQ.getConnection(RabbitMQ.java:56)
at com.urbanairship.octobot.ChannelPool.initialize(ChannelPool.java:54)
at com.urbanairship.octobot.ChannelPool$ResetShutdownListener.shutdownCompleted(ChannelPool.java:41)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ShutdownNotifierComponent.notifyListeners(ShutdownNotifierComponent.java:75)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:548)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown; reason: Attempt to use closed channel
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:190)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:223)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:209)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:202)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:340)
```

It starts showing 0 consumers in RabbitMq however service remains up in server.

Comment: These lines look strange: `com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure` and `Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown; reason: Attempt to use closed channel`

Comment: that is like generic exception that rabbit MQ throws in case of any error while creating connection.